# ADB - How to not display action results?

Tags: batch-file, adb, batch-processing

I am doing small toolkit with adb. And it is really annoying if everytime I type command
ADB PUSH or ADB PULL or any other adb command, it displays results:

2952 KB/s (4989129 bytes in 1.650s)

How can I disable displaying action results??

I have tried commnd ADB push "file" "destination" >nul

But it isn't working!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message you're seeing is being printed to the `stderr`. And you are only redirecting `stdout`. To suppress the message completely you need to redirect both:

```
adb push "file" "destination" >nul 2>&1
```